# Illegal inheritance multiple traits

Tags: scala

I want to inherit two classes (AbstractA and AbstractB) in some trait C:

```
abstract class AbstractA
trait A extends AbstractA

abstract class AbstractB
trait B extends AbstractB

trait C extends A with B
```

This code is not compiled:

> [error] illegal inheritance; superclass AbstractA is not a subclass of
>   the superclass AbstractB of the mixin trait B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't inherit from two different classes, and as a consequence you can't even inherit from two traits inheriting from two different classes.

```
 AbstractA  AbstractB
    |           |
    |           |
    A           B
     \         /
      \       /
       \     /
        \   /
          C
```

Were this allowed, `C` would be subclass of both `AbstractA` and `AbstractB`, which is illegal.

---

What's your use case anyway?

A trait can have abstract members so you shouldn't need to inherit from an abstract class at all.